# data type application/x-www-form-urlencoded from json error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have a problem:

I need to make a post to a php using json, but it responds only with the data type x-www-form-urlencoded, I used the postman of google chrome and not form-data is done, I used this way but tells me that the parameters are incorrect, I need help:

```
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"j_username=%@&j_password=%@",nombre,pass];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlhttp];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: you may consider make your life easier and start using [`AFNeworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: I don't see any JSON in your question.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella There is nothing easier about AFNetworing. The interface is different but not easier. You have to pass the same parameters.

Comment: You can pass the parameters as a dictionary, and the encoding will be automatically handled by `AFNetworking`. Yes, it's easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where's JSON in your example? You have nothing looking like it in the example.
You're doing a few things wrong in setting up the request, check Sulthan answer.

My advice is to use a library that handles such minor formal details - like encoding and headers - for you.

With [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) you could write something like.

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://whatever.com/"]];
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding]

NSDictionary * params = @{
                           @"j_username": nombre,
                           @"j_password": pass
                         };
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                        path:@"relative/path/to/resource"
                                                  parameters:params];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

(example based on http://samwize.com/2012/10/25/simple-get-post-afnetworking/)

While in terms on LOC in may look not so great, consider that:

- `httpClient` is initialized just once and you can reuse it for subsequent requests, centralizing the configuration
- parameters gets automatically encoded in the desired format and if you have to change the encoding in the future you just have to change `AFFormURLParameterEncoding` to something else.
- you get a nice block-based API instead of relying on the cumbersome `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods

Comment: Thanks hope I never have to deal with problems after the returned data, a question if I have this route:
http://www.pre.wesmartpark.com/backend/j_spring_security_check
the download directory is this? path: @ "backend / j_spring_security_check" thanks

Comment: base url: `http://pre.wesmartpark.com/`,  path: `backend/j_spring_security_check`

Answer (score 1):

For starters:

1. Your string has nothing to do with JSON. It's just a plain string
2. Your username & password must be URL encoded
3. `[NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]]` is wrong. You would have to use `[NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[[jsonRequest UTF8String] length]]`